# Re-order containers using media queries

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries

I'm wanting to re-order a number of containers when the webpage is being viewed on a particular device.

I currently have three divs floated left. Two smaller divs either side of a larger div. However, when the media query kicks in a would like the middle of the three to sit above the other two. In theory changing its position from 2nd to 1st.

Is this possible with pure CSS? Or would I need to get jQuery involved? I've set up a test fiddle here for anybody who can help with my initial attempts, but I'm having no joy so far... http://jsfiddle.net/r8qZ2/

Example HTML:

```
<div class="panels">
    <div class="panel-one">Panel 1</div>
    <div class="panel-two">Panel 2</div>
    <div class="panel-three">Panel 3 </div>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.panels {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.panel-one, .panel-three {
    width: 24.0625%;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;

    background: red;
}

.panel-three {
    margin: 0 0 0 1.25%;
}

.panel-two {
    width: 49.375%;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 1.25%;

    background: blue;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

.panel-one, .panel-three {
    width: 49%;
    height: 400px;
}

.panel-three {
    margin: 0 0 0 2%;
}

.panel-two {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    clear: left;
    margin: 0;
}

}
```

Any help would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

Re-order responsive containers with CSS? With `float` based layouts, no. In cases with just one floated sidebar it's possible, but not with two.

If you adjust your layout not to use `floats` then it's most certainly possible.

*Note: I highly recommend a mobile first-approach to your CSS, using `min-width` media queries. However since you're using `max-width` in your example I will also do so in mine:*

### Using `position: absolute`:

Place the element you want to be at the top as the first element in your HTML markup, and position the sidebars to the sides with `position: absolute`. Give the parent element `position: relative`, and give it a `padding` value equal to the `width` of the sidebars.

Then, with media queries, remove the `padding` and `position: absolute` you set.

**Example:**

HTML:

```
<div class="panels">
  <div class="panel-two">Panel 2</div>
  <div class="panel-one">Panel 1</div>
  <div class="panel-three">Panel 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panels {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 25%;
}

.panel-one,
.panel-three {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 25%;
}

.panel-one   { left: 0;  }
.panel-three { right: 0; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .panels {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .panel-one,
  .panel-three {
    position: static;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

[Here's a pen with your markup adjusted to this](http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/fKLqe?editors=110).

A major drawback to this is that the sidebars are taken out of the content flow with `position: absolute`, so depending on your layout this may not be a possible solution.